# Domain Mapping to point to a tag inside a service on Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run

right now I'm deploying to cloud run and run

```
gcloud run deploy myapp --tag pr123 --no-traffic
```

I can then access the app via

```
https://pr123---myapp-jo5dg6hkf-ez.a.run.app
```

Now I would like to have a custom domain mapping going to this tag. I know how to point a custom domain to the service but I don't know how to point it to the tagged version of my service.

Can I add labels to the DomainMapping that would cause the mapping to got this version of my cloud run service? Or is there a routeName, eg. myapp#pr123 that would do the trick there?

In the end I would like to have

```
https://pr123.dev.mydomain.com
```

being the endpoint for this service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a custom domain, you configure a DNS to point to a service, not a revision/tag of the service. So, you can't by this way.

The solution is to use a [load balancer with a serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless). The most important is to define the [URL mask](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#constructing-url-mask) that you want to map the tag and service from the URL which is received by the Load Balancer.

Comment: Sounds like too much work for a feature that is nice to have for my use case (testing environment with pull request builds). Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building the loadbalancer with a network endpoint group (as suggested). For further reference, here is my terraform snippet to create it. The  part is then the traffic tag you assign to your revision.

```
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "api_neg" {
  name                  = "api-neg"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = "europe-west3"
  cloud_run {
    service  = data.google_cloud_run_service.api_dev.name
    url_mask = "<tag>.preview.mydomain.com"
  }
}
```